# Why is there no badge for asking questions daily?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, badges

I don't know how badges work and if/how one can be created but I am surprised there is no badge for asking a question every day for 'X' number of days. Is there any reason why not? If not, is there any interest in creating one?

Comment: no source at the moment, but Stack Exchange prefers good answers over good questions. That's why there's a limit on how many questions one can ask a day (unless they changed that)

Answer (score 4):

I would oppose such a badge.

It would be wonderful if everyone used this site to ask about the *interesting* problems you encounter in your day-to-day activities. But when you're suddenly put on the spot to "ask questions daily," you'll likely end up with an influx of low-quality, uninspired questions.  Inspiration and intrigue doesn't run on a schedule.

Users should be asking real questions about problems they actually have. Don't add a badge or other incentive to force the issue. You won't likely get the results you are trying to encourage.

Comment: While it's definitely true that questions should be high quality and inspired, remember that on Mi Yodeya's FAQ we have: [Questions that appear to be requests for personal practical advice will be either edited to more general wording or closed.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#link-notes)

Answer (score 2):

I like this idea, or at least a variation thereof to encourage asking good questions. I think it would have to exclude negatively voted or duplicate questions, and possibly even questions with a score of less than some number (5?). I'm thinking along the lines of 10 straight days for a bronze badge; no silvers or golds.

Proposed name: Inquisitive.

---

<s>Although it seems this idea has been proposed and rejected on meta.SO [Badge for asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4587/166155)</s>

Something similar has recently been approved over on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/166155). I will hereby being taking credit for the badge name.

Comment: I also like this idea with your caveat of the question scoring above a certain threshold so as to obviate some of Robert's concerns.